# Maximizing with constraint for number of distinct SKU not greater than X

Tags: dataframe, optimization, pulp

I'm building a optimization tool using Pulp.

It's purpose is to define which SKU to take and which SKU to leave from each warehouse.

I'm having trouble with the following constraint:

"The maximum of different SKUs selected should not exceed 500"

That is to say, that no matter how many units you take, as long as they do not exceed 500 varieties (different SKUs), its all good.

This is what I've got so far

```
#simplex
df=pd.read_excel(ruta+"actual/202109.xlsx", nrows=20) #leemos la nueva base del mes

# Create variables and model
x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", df.index, lowBound=0)
mod = pulp.LpProblem("Budget", pulp.LpMaximize)


# Objective function
objvals = {idx: (1.0)*(df['costo_unitario'][idx]) for idx in df.index}
mod += sum([x[idx]*objvals[idx] for idx in df.index])


# Lower and upper bounds:
for idx in df.index:
    mod += x[idx] <= df['unidades_sobrestock'][idx]

# Budget sum
mod += sum([x[idx] for idx in df.index]) <= max_uni

# Solve model
mod.solve()

# Output solution
for idx in df.index:
    print (str(idx) + " " + str(x[idx].value()))


print ('Objective' + " " + str(pulp.value(mod.objective)))
```

In the same dataframe, I have a column with the SKU of each particular row df['SKU']

I'm imagining that the constraint should look something like:

```
for idx in df.index:

  mod += df['SKU'].count(distinct) <= 500
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: You should edit your post to include your current effort in `pulp` so that we can see how you have the problem set up, variables, etc.  And you should do yourself a *huge* favor and not commingle `pandas` with `pulp`.  You cannot put data frame functions into the model (like `count()` above).  Move your data into dictionaries and build your model from that...easier & less error prone.

Comment: Thanks @AirSquid

Comment: Are you familiar with "big M" constraints?  You'll probably need to introduce an additional binary variable (indexed same as `x`) in order to produce big-M constraints and have a variable to count the SKUs used.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a binary variable `y[i]` to indicate if a SKU is used. In math-like notation:

```
  x[i] ≤ maxx[i]*y[i]     (y[i] = 0 ==> x[i] = 0) 
  sum(i, y[i]) ≤ maxy     (limit number of different SKUs)
  y[i] ∈ {0,1}            (binary variable)
```

where

```
   maxx[i] = upperbound on x[i]
   maxy = limit on number of different SKUs
```

Comment: Hi Erwin, thanks a lot, I understand, but how can I tell the variable that some SKU is being used, in order to make the increment and evaluate if the condition is met?

Comment: `y[i]` keeps track if SKU i is used, If used (i.e. if `x[i]>0`) then it must be true that `y[i]=1`.

Comment: thanks! I'm trying to code it, as soon as I get it running I'll mark this as the answer. I'm just not too clear on the maxx[i]; what do you mean by upperbound on x[i]?

Comment: This approach is spot-on.  the `maxx[i]` is the maximum quantity of that can be used.  It it allows `x[i]` to go up to that max if `y[i]` == 1.  So if the available quantity of x[7] is 205, then maxx[7] = 205.   It is just a parameter in the model.